# Pygame crashes on init

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to use pygame, but I have not gotten very far on my mac because my python crashes why it tries to run `pygame.init()`.

I do not thing that it is a problem with anything else in my code because if I type `import pygame` into the python shell window and then type in `pygame.init` it still crashes.

Does it have to do with the version of pygame I am using? I am using 1.9.4.

Thanks

Comment: Please can you add the traceback (the error message) from when Python crashes to your question?

Comment: I don't get a traceback error. Python completely crashes and my computer gives me an option to ignore, or reopen python.

Comment: Please post your program, a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows us to reproduce the error. Also, tell us how you installed pygame and how you run the program.

Comment: Run it from a shell, it should tell you something when it crashes

Comment: I don't get anything in the shell, just a message from my mac saying that python as crashed.